# Evaluating $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1+y^2}dy$ without trig substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

A problem in our calculus text requires the evaluation of $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1+y^2}dy$,

and
I have evaluated it by substituting $y=\sin\theta$ (or $y=\tanh u$) and then using another substitution and partial fractions; but I would like to find out if there is a simpler way to find this integral that does not
involve trig substitution (or hyperbolic substitution).

(I know some MSE people dislike this type of question, so I apologize in advance.)

Comment: you can find it by Taylor series

Comment: @Essam, sounds pretty gruesome.

Comment: You can solve this using the method of contour integration, but this is maybe bnot what you want

Comment: Another way of doing this is the so called euler substituion. But i'm not sure if you will be really faster. Nevertheless, it will work out definitly

Comment: @tired I would be interested in seeing both of the methods you mentioned.

Comment: You can also use hyperbolic trig substitution or Euler substitution. I once [wrote a post](http://davidlowryduda.com/?p=1723) evaluating one integral with all three techniques. They all work in high generality.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint:

$$t=y^2$$

$$dy=\frac{1}{2\sqrt t}dt$$

then

$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1-t}{t}}}{1+t}dt$$
$$\frac{1-t}{t}=u^2$$

so$$t=\frac{1}{1+u^2} $$

$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^2}{(u^2+1)(u^2+2)}du=\int_0^{\infty}(\frac{2}{u^2+2}-\frac{1}{u^2+1})du$$
then you can solve it without trigonometric substitution by knowing that

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^2+1}du=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: very  neat! (+1)

Answer (score 7):

I will try to give an approach to this integral using complex analysis:

First of all we would like to have a form of the integral which is most easily tractable by contour integration, which (at least for me) means that

- it is as obivious as possible to guess a contour which can be used
- the pole/cut structure is as clear as possible

One way of doing so, is exploiting the parity of the integrand and transform $y\rightarrow 1/x$. We get:
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}P\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{1+x^2}dx
$$

Here $P$ denotes Cauchy's principal value.
We now may consider the complex function

$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{z}\frac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{1+z^2}
$$

Choosing the standard branch of logarithm, we have a cut on the interval $[-1,1]$, furthermore we have singularities at $\{\pm i,0\}$ where the first two are harmless but the one at zero is on the cut and will need to be handeled with care.

Now may choose a contour which encloses the branch cut, and avoids the singularity at 0. we get:

$$
\oint f(z)dz = \underbrace{\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}f(x_+)+\int_{\epsilon}^{1}f(x_+)}_{2I}+\int_{\text{arg}(z)\in(\pi,0], |z|=\epsilon}f(z)dz\\-\underbrace{\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}f(x_-)-\int_{\epsilon}^{1}f(x_-)}_{-2I}-\int_{\text{arg}(z)\in[0,-\pi), |z|=\epsilon}f(z)dz=\\
4I+\underbrace{2\int_{\text{arg}(z)\in(\pi,0], |z|=\epsilon}f(z)dz}_{2 \times \pi i\ \times \text{res}[f(z),z=0] }=\\
4I +2\pi \quad (1)
$$

Where $\text{res}[f(z),z=0]=i$ because we calculated the residue above the branch cut. Furthermore $f(x_{\pm})$ denotes about which side of the cut we are talking: $\pm$ above/below. Also the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ is implicit.

Now comes the trick: 
By looking at the exterior of the contour we can also write  (please note that we now enclose the singularities in opposite direction compared to above)

$$
\oint f(z)dz=-2\pi i \times(\text{res}[f(z),z=i]+
\text{res}[f(z),z=-i])=2\sqrt{2}\pi \quad (2)
$$

Equating $(1)=(2)$

$$
4I+2\pi=2\sqrt{2}\pi\\
$$
or
$$
I=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)
$$

which is the same result as the one obtained by trig. substitution.

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer.  (There may be a sign error, though.)

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. i will a have a look at it later!

Answer (score 6):

Let us take the "gruesome" path.
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx&=&\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n+2)}\\&=&\frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n(n+1)}\binom{2n}{n}=\left.\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{x}\right|_{x=-1}\\&=&\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)}.\end{eqnarray*}$$
Not so painful, after all, if one recalls the generating function of the [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Steps involved:

- expansion of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ as a geometric series;
- integration of $x^{\alpha}(1-x)^{\beta}$ over $[0,1]$ through the Euler beta function;
- rewriting in terms of central binomial coefficients;
- evaluation through the generating function for the Catalan numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which doesn't look so gruesome after all.  If you have time, though, would you please explain your 2nd and 3rd equalities (or provide a link that would help me understand them).

Comment: @user84413: I added a brief explanation of the steps involved.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $y=\dfrac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}$ :

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1+y^2} \, dy \\ 
&= \int_0^1 \frac{4z^2}{(1+z^2)(1+z^4)} \, dz \\
&= \int_0^1 \left(-\frac2{1+z^2} + \frac{1}{1-\sqrt2\,z+z^2} + \frac{1}{1+\sqrt2\,z+z^2}\right) \, dz \\
&= -2\arctan 1 - \sqrt2 \arctan\left(1-\sqrt2\right) + \sqrt2 \arctan\left(1+\sqrt2\right) \\
&= -\frac\pi2+\frac{\sqrt2\,\pi}8 + \frac{3\sqrt2\,\pi}8 = \boxed{\frac{\sqrt2-1}2\pi}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: This substitution is, perhaps up to some signs, Euler's Third Substitution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution#Euler's_third_substitution

Answer (score 1):

The *indefinite integral* is
$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1+y^2} dy = -\arcsin(y) - 
\sqrt{2}\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\;y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right) + C
$$
so of course it is most easily done with a trig substitution.

Sometimes a *definite integral* can be done without first doing the indefinite integral.  As another answer suggests,
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1+y^2} dy = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1+y^2} dy
$$
and that integral is amenable to a solution by residues in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is "simpler" than trig substitution, but here's a method that makes no mention of trigonometric functions, uses a technically easier contour integration, and exploits some perhaps nonobvious symmetry of the integrand. Euler's Second Substitution,
$$\sqrt{1 - y^2} = - 1 + y u,$$
rationalizes the integral:
$$I := 2 \int_1^\infty \frac{(u^2 - 1)^2 \,du}{(u^2 + 1)(u^4 + 6 u^2 + 1)} .$$
Denote the integrand in $u$ by $f(u)$ for later use. The substitution $u \rightsquigarrow \frac{1}{u}$ gives that
$$I = 2 \int_0^1 \frac{(u^2 - 1)^2 \,du}{(u^2 + 1)(u^4 + 6 u^2 + 1)},$$
hence
$$I = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{(u^2 - 1)^2 \,du}{(u^2 + 1)(u^4 + 6 u^2 + 1)} .$$
As the integrand is even we have
$$I = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(u^2 - 1)^2 \,du}{(u^2 + 1)(u^4 + 6 u^2 + 1)},$$
and this latter integral is a good candidate for application of the Residue Theorem.

Let $\Gamma_R$ denote boundary of the half-disk of radius $R$ centered at the origin in the upper half-plane. For $R > 1 + \sqrt{2}$, the poles of the integrand inside $\Gamma_R$ are at $i, (\sqrt{2} \pm 1) i$, so
\begin{align}
\oint_{\Gamma_R} f(z) \,dz \\
&= 2 \pi i \left[\operatorname{Res}(f(z), (\sqrt{2} - 1)i) + \operatorname{Res}(f(z), i) + \operatorname{Res}(f(z), (\sqrt{2} + 1) i)\right]\\
&= 2 \pi i \left(-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{2}} + \frac{i}{2} - \frac{i}{2 \sqrt{2}} \right) \\
&= \pi (\sqrt{2} - 1) .
\end{align}
A standard argument shows that for large $R$ the value of the integral over the semicircular contour is $O(R^{-1})$. So, taking limits gives
$$I = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u) \,du = \frac{1}{2} \oint_{\Gamma_R} f(z) \,dz = \color{#bf0000}{\boxed{\frac{\pi}{2} (\sqrt{2} - 1)}} .$$