# Integrate $ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$ without using Hyperbolic Functions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I originally had to solve this Integral:

> $$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$

It was suggested to me that I introduce the parameter $a$ and then try Differentiation Under the Integral Sign. I thus rewrote the Integral as 
$$ I(a)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}(ax)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$
$$\Longrightarrow I'(a)= \int_0^1\dfrac{y}{(1+(ay)^2)(\sqrt{1-y^2})}dy$$
I then thought I might try Integration By Parts with $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ in the denominator as the derivative of $\sin^{-1}(y)$. However, I don't understand how this would help. My friend suggested using hyperbolic functions but I don't know anything about them. $$$$
Would somebody please be so kind as to show me how to solve this problem? Many, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Trig substitution...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317564/evaluating-displaystyle-int-01-frac-sqrt1-y21y2dy-without-trig-subs/1318403#1318403

Maybe you find some inspration here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $y=\sin\left(u\right)
 $, we get $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin\left(u\right)}{1+a^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)}du=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin\left(u\right)}{a^{2}+1-a^{2}\cos^{2}\left(u\right)}du.
 $$ Now put $\cos\left(u\right)=v
 $, then $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{a^{2}+1-a^{2}v^{2}}dv=\frac{1}{a^{2}+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-\frac{a^{2}v^{2}}{a^{2}+1}}dv
 $$ and finally put $\frac{av}{\sqrt{a^{2}+1}}=t
 $ to get $$\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a^{2}+1}}\int_{0}^{a/\sqrt{a^{2}+1}}\frac{1}{1-t^{2}}dt=\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a^{2}+1}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^{2}+1}}\right)=\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a^{2}+1}}\log\left(\sqrt{a^{2}+1}+a\right)
 $$ using the identity, for $x<1$ $$\tanh^{-1}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right).$$

Comment: Sir, could you please give a closed form which does not involve Hyperbolic Functions?

Comment: Sir, as per what I was told, if we take $$ f(a) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(ax)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx $$then $$f'(a) = \frac{\ln(a+\sqrt{1+a^2})}{a\sqrt{1+a^2}}$$ Also, how would we then Integrate $f'(a)$?

Comment: @BetterWorld You can use, if you prefer, the facts that if $x<1$ holds $$\tanh^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks Sir. But Sir, please could you explain to me how to get $$f'(a) = \frac{\ln(a+\sqrt{1+a^2})}{a\sqrt{1+a^2}}$$ from $$f(a) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(ax)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

Comment: Sir, please could you explain how you got this step: $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{a^{2}+1-a^{2}v^{2}}dv=\frac{1}{a+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-\frac{a^{2}v^{2}}{a+1}}dv$$ According to me, it seems to be $a^2+1$ instead of $a+1$, Sir.

Comment: There was an error,thank you.

Comment: Note that, using the identity I wrote in the previous comment, you have $f'(a)$.

Comment: the integration w.r.t $a$ looks disgusting

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** You might want to use the fact that: $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\dfrac{\partial \arcsin(x)}{\partial x}=-\dfrac{\partial \arccos(x)}{\partial x}$$